# How to check if file hash has changed with C#

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I am a game devoloper, When i release a new games, BOOM!!!, That game will be modded, and i am running online games, Soo it's huge lose for me, I am making games with Unity, Hope u guys can understand me, I want to add HashCheck to the games main file, Like "If file hash changed, Game,close"

Like :- I have Assembly-CSharp.dll as my main game data file, So if Modders want to mod my games, They Will just load Assembly-CSharp.dll into some decompiler and Edit the file

I have also tried "HEX" Protection, But they Bypasses it

So, I want to make, When Modders change Assembly-CSharp.dll the hash will be changed,
If Hash chnaged "Application.quit"

I am just trying to compare MD5 hash

But i am not getting, Even sample code anyware

I just need code to add HashCheck in 
Assembly-CSharp.dll

Mean I need C# code

Comment: How do game mods constitute a huge loss for you?

Comment: Because, if there is a mod for my game, No one will buy the coins for Real money, Any how as it is Online game, Coins cannot be Modded, But there are Good features, Which will give Extreame Coins

Comment: I don't know anything about your particular game, but my experience with online games has been that you make a critical feature dependent on server-side check for credits (coins). That way, the client experience is severely degraded or non-playable if the user has no credits.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Sounds like **strong-name assembly-signing** might help you.</strike>

Amongst others, one benefit of strong-naming your assemblies is that they are **signed with a digital signature**, which **protects the assembly from being tampered with**.
If someone is to modify your assembly, the verification process which automatically occurs during assembly load will fail and throw an exception.

> Strong names provide a strong integrity check [...] [, guaranteeing] that the contents of the assembly have not been changed since it was build.

<sub>Taken from [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/wd40t7ad(v=vs.71)).</sub>

---

Read more about how to use strong-naming [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name).

---

## EDIT

As [toATwork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243584/toatwork) has mentioned, **strong-naming will *not* be of benefit** here. Strong-naming insures your users that your assembly really comes from you and was not modified by others.

Users that *want* to modify your assembly will not be discouraged from tampering with your assembly!

Since hash checks can easily be bypassed as well, what I recommend is to use **obfuscation in combination with** [**tamper checks**](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_checks_tamper.html). You could use Dotfuscator, which is already [included in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Strong name check can be bypassed. Strong names are for your customer to verify that the assembly is really from you and has not been tampered with (but from customers point of view!).

Comment: @toATwork Thank you for your comment, very good point. But, then again, inbuilt hash-checks can be tampered with (or even be completely bypassed) far easier. In my opinion, one of the best ways to go is to use [obfuscation with inbuilt tamper-checks](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_checks_tamper.html).

Comment: I totally agree with you in all points - except the on I commented on ;-)

Comment: @toATwork I will edit my answer to include your point, if you consent?

Comment: Ya!, I know Hash checks can be Bypassed by Modders, But by only Expert modders, Any how i will not only keep hash check at one place, I will keep in all Assemblies to cross check, Another Assemblies, and I will keep it self check too, And if possible i will try Signature and Root Checks too, But Bro, Place I need a code for Hash check, Let me try , And coming to Obfuscation, Dotfuscator layer of Obfuscation can be easily Removed

Comment: @SaiShashank oh, Dotfuscator obfuscation is actually pretty efficient, and not as easy to bypass as you may think...

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, Bro any how, Dotfuscator cannot Obfuscate all the Classes,Methods,Strings etc..., It will only Obfuscate 2% in 100%, But 2% is not good Right???, Even Bro I will be happy if u give me a Algorithm, Which will Obfuscate All the Code :)

Comment: @SaiShashank I'm just trying to help you :) Well, if you run it in "library mode", yes, almost nothing will be obfuscated. But if you [do not run it in library mode](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_library_mode.html), it will obfuscate all the internal, private etc. methods and types. It will introduce new overloads and can also inject way safer tamper checks than what you could possible write yourself. You can visit the links in my answer for more information.